# Ошибка отладчика репостов Facebook URLs cannot be crawled

Tags: wordpress, facebook, opengraph, микроразметка

Столкнулся с проблемой.Не работает Open Graph в Facebook. Везде работает, кроме FB. В чем может быть проблема? Сайт на ВП, плагинов кеша нет. Установлен Yoast Seo. Сылка: https://cinema.in.ua/
Разметка прописана правильно. Не знаю почему facebook не может просканировать мой URL

Comment: Попробуйте добавить <meta og:image...>

Comment: Все на месте. Facebook URLs cannot be crawled.

Comment: Где есть? В коде на сайте нет у вас этого

Comment: <meta property="og:image" content="https://cinema.in.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/cbd1c678834552dbc4dc4244365cb8177867f5bf.jpg"/>

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fcinema.in.ua%2Ftina-karol-i-solistka-hurtu-the-hardkiss-iuliia-sanina-zapysaly-holovnyj-saundtrek-do-filmu-viddana%2F
Исправьте ошибки и варнинги

Comment: type есть а, меня больше беспокоит Facebook URLs cannot be crawled. Не знаю что с этим делать